# Scala Stateless Functions

Tags: scala

What am I doing wrong? For instance, this should return 10:

```
{ val (get, set) = getAndSet (5); set (10); get () }
```

---

```
val getAndSet : Int => (() => Int, Int => Unit) = {
var s : Int = 0
val get : () => Int = () => {
  val z = s;
  s = s + 1;
  z
}
val set : Int => Unit = (x:Int) => {
  s = x
}
x => (get, set)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple of errors:

- `n` doesn't exist, you probably mean `s`.
- the last line should be `x => (get, set)`, although you're not using `x` in any way.

Here's the least modified version of your code that works

```
val getAndSet: Int => (() => Int, Int => Unit) = {
  var s: Int = 0
  val get : () => Int = () => {
    val z = s;
    s = s + 1;
    z
  }
  val set : Int => Unit = (x:Int) => {
    s = x
  }
  x => (get, set)
}
```

Since you're not using `x`, you can alternatively do

```
val getAndSet: Int => (() => Int, Int => Unit) = _ => {
  var s: Int = 0
  val get : () => Int = () => {
    val z = s;
    s = s + 1;
    z
  }
  val set : Int => Unit = (x:Int) => {
    s = x
  }
  (get, set)
}
```

Comment: My apologies, I didn't see my typing error. My code compiles though but it does not pass the test. I also think that "s = s + 1;" should be an equality, how would I turn that into an equality? would it be like "s.Equal(s+1)" ?